# cakephp router redirect using route elements

Tags: cakephp, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I changed the links' structure in my site adding a new route element, and I want to redirect old links adding a default for the new route element.

i.e the previous urls where like this: `mysite.com/category/product-name/`

and I changed to look like this: `mysite.com/store-section/category/product-name/`

I want the old links to redirect to the new ones adding a default store-section element to them. I think I can't achieve this with mod_rewrite because categories are parsed from the database with a custom routeClass.

Is it possible to use route elements in `Router::redirect()` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Since I haven't found a way using Router::redirect()  I kept mi original routes:

```
Router::connect("/:category/:product-name/*", 
    array(
        'controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view'
    ), 
    array(
        'routeClass' => 'CategoryRouteClass', 
        'pass' => array('category', 'product-name')
    )
);
```

and added new routes to match the new URLs, pointing to the same method and the same controller, but adding the new route element and passing it as a method argument:

```
Router::connect("/:store-section/:category/:product-name/*", 
    array(
        'controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view'
    ), 
    array(
        'routeClass' => 'CategoryRouteClass', 
        'pass' => array('category', 'product-name', 'store-section')
    )
);
```

...then in view method in products controller I check if the store-section parameter is set, 
if it is not I issue a redirect adding the default store-section to the current URL, like this :

```
Class ProductsController extends AppController {
    public function view($category= null, $product-name = null, 
        $store-section = null) {

        if (empty($store-section)) {
            $this->redirect(array(
                'controller' => 'products', 'action' => 'view', 
                'category' => $category,
                'product-name' => $product-name, 
                'store-section' => 'default-section'), '301');
        }

        //.................
    }
}
```

This succesfully issue a 301 for the old products urls to the new ones, useful for SEO and to keep old inbound links working in Cakephp.